# embed show hide in JS toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am seeking to embed and trigger a show / hide within this toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function() {
$('#toggle1').click(function () {
    $('.toggle').hide('1000');
    $('.toggle').html('I would like to show a new div within this toggle'); 
$('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

return false; 
    });
});
```

So kind of like a toggle within a toggle.

Bigger picture and ultimately; I am trying to do this within multiple embeds and instances creating a small game -- and seeking the lightest and best solution.

Click this > this triggers > within that DIV you can click a color > BOOM!

That is the drift.

I am seeking a solution that makes sense.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try organizing your elements to avoid any duplicate content. You could structure your HTML like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Select item -->
    <div class="select_item">
        <ul class="item_list">
            <li class="item active" data-item-id="1"><img class="item_thumb" src="1.jpg"></li>
            <li class="item" data-item-id="2"><img class="item_thumb" src="2.jpg"></li>
            <li class="item" data-item-id="3"><img class="item_thumb" src="3.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Select color -->
    <div class="select_color">
        <ul class="color_list">
            <li class="color active" data-color-id="1"><span class="color_thumb"><!-- Color --></span></li>
            <li class="color" data-color-id="2"><span class="color_thumb"><!-- Color --></span></li>
            <li class="color" data-color-id="3"><span class="color_thumb"><!-- Color --></span></li>
            <li class="color" data-color-id="4"><span class="color_thumb"><!-- Color --></span></li>
            <li class="color" data-color-id="5"><span class="color_thumb"><!-- Color --></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and accomplish the selection behavior like this:

```
function getSelection() {
    var selection = { };
        selection['item_id'] = parseInt($('.item.active').attr('data-item-id'));
        selection['color_id'] = parseInt($('.color.active').attr('data-color-id'));
    return selection;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Update the current item
    $('.item_thumb').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.item').removeClass('active');
        $(e.currentItem).parent().addClass('active');
    });
    //Update the current color
    $('.color_thumb').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.color').removeClass('active');
        $(e.currentItem).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

This is assuming that every parent item requires you to choose a color (i.e. – the same type of option). If your root items each require different option types (e.g. – color, size, etc), you could try nesting each item's options within the item container:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Contains all items with options -->
    <ul class="items">
        <!-- Item 1, has a color option -->
        <li class="item active" data-item-id="1">
            <div class="item_thumb"><img src="item1.jpg"></div>
            <ul class="options">
                <li class="option active" data-option-id="1"><span class="color_thumb"><!-- Color --></span></li>
                <li class="option" data-option-id="2"><span class="color_thumb"><!-- Color --></span></li>
                <li class="option" data-option-id="3"><span class="color_thumb"><!-- Color --></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- Item 2, has a size option -->
        <li class="item" data-item-id="2">
            <div class="item_thumb"><img src="item2.jpg"></div>
            <ul class="options">
                <li class="option active" data-option-id="1"><span class="size_label">Small</span></li>
                <li class="option" data-option-id="2"><span class="size_label">Medium</span></li>
                <li class="option" data-option-id="3"><span class="size_label">Large</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and accomplish the selection behavior like this:

```
function getSelection() {
    var current_item = $('.item.active');
    var selection = { };
        selection['item_id'] = parseInt(current_item.attr('data-item-id'));
        selection['item_option'] = current_item.find('.option.active').attr('data-option-id');
    return selection;
}
```

Your page could get much more complex depending on the depth of your options (option -> suboption -> sub-suboption), which could require some more case-specific code. While I don't understand your exact requirements (or what you meant by 'toggle'), this may help get you going in the right direction.